# Registering iPhone for development without Xcode

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I'm developing an iPhone app, and would like to distribute it to some of my non-technical friends and family members for testing and feedback. I've got their UDIDs, and I've added them to my provisioning profile, but they still can't load the app or the profile.

I've got a feeling that they need to have their phones enabled for development, which is fine for local folks, since I can plug their phones into Xcode. What I don't know is how to deal with remote, non-technical people. Is there any way for them to enable their phones using iTunes so that they can load development builds, or does the phone absolutely positively have to be plugged in to Xcode? Most of my friends outside the valley don't even know anyone with a Mac, let alone a developer. Is there any way I can get them testing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a walkthrough on how to use an ad-hoc distribution.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Create an ad-hoc distribution.  The [Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/distribution.action) has walkthroughs on what to do.